# jquery click() in submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, click, submit

I have a .click() function on a submit button in a form:

```
$("#submitId").click(function () {
    $('#hiddenInput').val(someVariable);
});
```

It works like a charm. When the submit button is clicked the click() function fills the hidden input variable and then the whole form gets submitted. The server then receives the hidden input with the refreshed content.

My question is: will it always work? Is there any danger that, by some reason not yet known to me, the submit operation gets executed first and the click() function later? I want to make sure the hidden input always gets refreshed.

Comment: $("form").submit(); will bypass that, a user could execute the call from their console or url.

Comment: And I assume it might also get bypassed when just pressing ENTER to submit the form? Give it a try.

Comment: @JamesBlond - Enter will still cause the click handler to execute.

Comment: The click event always fully executes first. Otherwise how would you ever stop a submit with prevent default. [For Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault)

Comment: @TravisJ - If focus is on the button, `enter` will cause the click handler to execute.  But if the focus is on one of the form fields, `enter` will bypass the click handler, because there was no interaction with the button (just with the form).  I think.

Comment: @Wrightboy - You can also call Event.preventDefault() in the submit handler.

Answer (score 26):

When working with forms, it's **always** advisable to let the `submit` button do it's job: **TRIGGER THE FORM'S SUBMIT EVENT** ... that's what it's meant for. Then you would listen for the `submit` event on the `form` rather than the `click` event on the `submit` button.

You can use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent default submission of the form so that you can do some *house keeping* then you can submit the form.

```
$("#submitId").closest('form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#hiddenInput').val(someVariable); //perform some operations
    this.submit(); //now submit the form
});
```

Or simply,

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#hiddenInput').val(someVariable); //perform some operations
    this.submit(); //now submit the form
});
```

Comment: This does not work if your submit button uses `formaction`.
I recommend either triggering the submit button with a `click` event or assigning the value of `formaction` to the `action` property of the form and then triggering the `submit` event.

Comment: @kevinAdu what do you mean? Do you have a demo to illustrate your concern? Thank you.

Comment: won't this make it loop forever? on submit... then re-submit

Comment: @Claudiu why do you think it would loop forever? If you can creating a demo to illustrate your concern, I would be more than happy to take that into consideration. Looking forward .....

Comment: Please bear in mind that `this.submit()` is not the same as `$(this).submit()`.

Comment: This way the value of the `submit` input won't be sent. In case you have `isset($_POST["submit_btn_name"])`

Answer (score 4):

It would be best to attach the value update directly to the form's submit handler like this

```
$("#submitId").closest("form").submit(function () {
 $('#hiddenInput').val(someVariable);
});
```

Comment: This is it. A submit event can be fired in various ways. Instead of trying to guess how a user might fire a submit event (click? keypress?), just attach your handler directly to the form's submit.

Comment: This will not work though if the submit button is embedded in some element inside the form. I would use `.closest('form')` instead of `.parent('form')`.

Comment: @PeterKA - Yes, that is a good point. Edited `parent` to `closest`.

Answer (score 1):

I personally think it is safer to prevent submit, then set value of input needed and only then submit the form programmatically. Like:

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#hiddenInput').val(someVariable);
    $(this).submit();
});
```

Comment: Because  $(this).submit(); triggers the submit event, this code will create an endless loop. What you want to use is an action that simply submits the form without triggering the submit event.

Answer (score -1):

The .click() should always be run first.

Comment: More of a comment than an answer. At least provide some source to back that up.