# Why doesn't work properly with regular expressions?

Tags: jquery

i want to validate name,phone,surname,email, but when I want to submit it doesn't work.. i tried to change my expressions, but nothing.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#ok').on('click',function(){
           var name = $('#txtNombre').val();
           var surname = $('#txtApellido').val();
           var email = $('#txtCorreo').val();
           var phone = $('#txtTelefono').lengh;
           if(name == null || name.length == 0 || /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/.test(name)){
                $("#txtNombre").css('border-color','red');
           }else{
             $("#txtNombre").css('border-color','');
           }
           if(surname == null || surname.length == 0 || /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/.test(surname)){
                $("#txtApellido").css('border-color','red');
           }else{
             $("#txtApellido").css('border-color','');
           }
           if(email == null || email.length == 0 || /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+.(com|com.mx|es|edu.mx)$/.test(email)){
                $("#txtCorreo").css('border-color','red');
           }else{
             $("#txtCorreo").css('border-color','');
           }
           if(phone == null || phone.length == 0 || /^[0-9]+$/.test(phone)){
                $("#txtTelefono").css('border-color','red');
           }else{
             $("#txtTelefono").css('border-color','');
           }
        });
        $('#cancel').on('click',function(){
            $('#txtNombre, #txtApellido, #txtCorreo, #txtTelefono').val('');
             $('#txtNombre, #txtApellido, #txtCorreo, #txtTelefono').css('border-color','');
        });
    });
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is a bit vague.  What behavior are you expecting and what behavior are you getting?  Please update the question.

Answer (score -1):

You may be mixing click events with submit events.

Please check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26747158/169252